# How to return boolean based on number of records in database?

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

Here's what I've tried. My host is returning an error, "Sorry an unexpected error happened!" .

I want it to return true if there is at least 1 record with combination pdriver_id, ptruck_number, and pdate.

```
DELIMITER %%
CREATE FUNCTION DriverActiveInTruckByDate(
    pdriver_id INT,
    ptruck_number INT,
    pdate DATETIME
) 
RETURNS boolean
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE inDB INT DEFAULT 0;
    SET inDB = 
        SELECT IF(COUNT(*) >= 1,1,0)
    FROM
        truck_timeline tl
    WHERE 1=1
        AND tl.driver_id = pdriver_id
        AND tl.truck_number = ptruck_number
        AND ((pdate BETWEEN tl.begin_date AND tl.end_date) OR (pdate >= tl.begin_date AND tl.end_date IS NULL))
    
END
%%
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: can you provide scripts with table, inserts and the function (if it was changed from above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several fixes are needed:

- The function is not `DETERMINISTIC`. This means the result will always be the same given the same inputs. In your case, the result may be different depending on the data in your `truck_timeline` table. So I would suggest using `READS SQL DATA`.
- If you use `SET variable = SELECT...` you must put the SELECT in a subquery:

  ```
  SET inDB = (SELECT ...);
  ```
- The current manual recommends using `SELECT ... INTO variable` instead of `SET`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html

  > The INTO position at the end of the statement is supported as of MySQL 8.0.20, and is the preferred position.

  ```
  SELECT ... INTO inDB;
  ```
- The function you show doesn't have a `RETURN` statement.   See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/return.html

  > There must be at least one RETURN statement in a stored function.

Answer (score 1):

Your Full Code could be like this:

```
DELIMITER %%
CREATE FUNCTION DriverActiveInTruckByDate(
    pdriver_id INT,
    ptruck_number INT,
    pdate DATETIME
) 
RETURNS boolean
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE inDB INT DEFAULT 0; 
        SET inDB = 
        (SELECT IF(COUNT(*) >= 1,1,0)
    FROM
        truck_timeline tl
    WHERE 1=1
        AND tl.driver_id = pdriver_id
        AND tl.truck_number = ptruck_number
        AND ((pdate BETWEEN tl.begin_date AND tl.end_date) OR (pdate >= tl.begin_date AND tl.end_date IS NULL))
        );
END %%
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: If you use assignment in an expression, you should use `:=` instead of `=`. If you use `=`, it's comparison, not assignment.